# is there any way to calculate date in airflow?

Tags: airflow

i create a Dag that will be scheduled to run every day once a day - the dag wont get any parameters . each day the dag ran i need to calculate yesterdays date (current Date -1)  and pass it for all the operators in the dag (same date). 
i saw that i can use Airflow-macros to compute the date , but the problem is ,the operator i use in t2 (must use this operator and cant change it) pass the data to the dictionary (default_param_dict) as a string and don't compute the macro.

is there any other way to compute the date without macros? using X-com is not relevant because i can only use the operators and cant change their code.

need you help:)

adding my dag example:

```py
t1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='check_if_daily_report_ready',
    method='GET',
    endpoint="/bla/bla?date={date}".format(
        date='{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}'),
    http_conn_id="conn1",
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    response_check=lambda response: True if response.status_code == 200 else False,
    dag=dag,
)



t2 = Queryperator(
    task_id='cal',
    query_file='ca.sql',
    query_folder='include/sql_files/bla',
    token='Token',
    default_param_dict={"date": '{{ (execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}'},
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question, you wanted to add yesterday's date the default_param_dict, if so, I would recommend using the datetime, something like below,

```
import datetime

t2 = Queryperator(
    task_id='cal',
    query_file='ca.sql',
    query_folder='include/sql_files/bla',
    token='Token',
    default_param_dict={"date": (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')},
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: thx for your answer! will this calculate the date every scheduled dag run?

Comment: it should calculate.